# Run multiple process from a cat

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to do a script which can run multiple process from a cat file and it runs from 100 to 100 process.

I have 3 files:
ip.txt: File containing ip's and some variables that need to be passed to the pingandsnmp.sh script
run.sh: Script that I want to run multiple pingandsnmp.sh process. If te ip.txt has 350 lines, I want to run 100 process every minute.

Ip.txt example:

```
200.236.71.184,ab,operator1
200.236.74.210,aa,operator1
200.236.75.66,aa,operator2
200.236.69.70,ad,operator3
```

run.sh example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program: run.sh

for i in $(cat ip.txt)
do
    sh ./pingandsnmp.sh
done
```

pingandsnmp.sh example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program: pingandsnmp.sh

    case $2 in
    "aa")
        echo "ab"
    case $3 in
        "operator1")
        ping=`ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -W 1 "$1"`
        pingresponse=$?
        snmp=`snmpget -v2c -c public -r 0 -t 1 "$1" system.sysDescr.0`
        snmpresponse=$?
        echo "$pingresponse"
        echo "$snmpresponse"
        echo "operator1"
        ;;
        "operator2")
        ping=`ping -c 1 -i 0.2 -W 1 "$1"`
        pingresponse=$?
        snmp=`snmpget -v2c -c public -r 0 -t 1 "$1" system.sysDescr.0`
        snmpresponse=$?
        echo "$pingresponse"
        echo "$snmpresponse"
        echo "operator2"
    esac
;;
esac
```

I need to pass the variables from ip.txt to pingandsnmp.sh and run multiple process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into `xargs`?

Comment: First pass the IP where ip can be ip="$(echo $i | cut -d',' -f1)" and then pass it to pingandsnmp.sh as "sh ./pingandsnmp.sh $ip" in run.sh. Best way would be to call pingandsnmp in background i.e. "use &" and then use "ps" command to check how many instances of pingandsnmp processes are running in within 60 seconds, if less than 100 then call/run more instances otherwise wait until the # of instances go down under 100). Got it?